# How to study convergence of this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have the following series:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n\cos(x)^n}{n^2+2}
\end{equation}
I am restudying series and I'm really rusty, and do not know how to begin to study the convergence of this thing. It will depend of course on $x$. Do I have to set $\cos(x)=z$ and study the following power series, 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{nz^n}{n^2+2}
\end{equation}
trying to find the radius of convergence? Any hints?

Comment: Well, you don't **have** to "set cos(x)= z" but that's not a bad idea. It does obscure the fact that $-1\le z= cos(x)\le 1$.  And then cos(x) to any power lies between -1 and 1.  You might want to consider three cases: cos(x)= -1, -1< cos(x)< 1, and cos(x)= 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a calculus class, it is better to observe that $-1 \leq \cos x \leq 1$, giving four easily discerned behaviours.

- $\cos x = -1$: This is the series $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n}{n^2+2}$, which you have other tools for.
- $-1 < \cos x < 0$: Your series is $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n}{n^2+2} |\cos x|^n$ and $$  0 < \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{n}{n^2+2} |\cos x|^n \leq \sum_{n \geq 1} |\cos x|^n  \text{,}  $$ so your series is a positive series bounded by a geometric series.
- $\cos x = 0$: Easy.
- $0 < \cos x$: Now you have an alternating series.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish 3 cases.

If $\cos x\ne \pm 1$, then you have

$$\Big|(-1)^n \frac{n(\cos x)^n}{n^2+2}\Big|\le |\cos x|^n$$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |\cos x|^n=\frac{1}{1-|\cos x|}-1,$$

which shows that the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{n(\cos x)^n}{n^2+2}$  converges absolutely in this case.

If $\cos x=-1$, then you get the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^2+2},$$
which is divergent (basically the harmonic series).

If $\cos x=1$, then you get the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{n}{n^2+2},$$
which is not absolutely convergent. However, this series still converges because you can find $C>0$ such that

$$ \Big|\frac{n}{n^2+2}-\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^2+2} \Big| \le \frac{C}{n^2} \quad\forall n\ge 1.$$